Discrete Fresnel operator
In mathematical optics, the Fresnel propagator is defined as the transfer function
\begin{equation}
    T( x,  y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{i\lambda d}}\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{\lambda d}| x- y|^2\right)
\end{equation}
between two points $x,y\in \mathbb R$. The constants $\lambda, d$ represent the wavelength of the radiation and the distance travelled respectively. It can be easily shown that such an operator is unitary:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dy \ T^\dagger(x,y)T(y, x')=\delta(x-x'). $$
I'm looking for the correct discrete version of this operator. On a finite support of length $L$, one can define a step size $\Delta=L/N$ to get $N$ points at positions $x_n=x_0+n\Delta$; then the most natural definition for the discrete propagator would be $T_{nm}:=T(x_n, x_m)$. However, this matrix is no longer unitary.
Is there a way to define a matrix that is compatible with the original Fresnel operator in the continuum limit, whilst preserving the unitary property for any finite $N$?

Bonus: in many cases, the Fraunhofer approximation
\begin{equation}
    T'( x,  y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{i\lambda d}}\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{\lambda d}(y^2-2xy)\right)
\end{equation}
can be considered. This is still a unitary operator, and I feel that the task of discretizing this operator would be a bit easier (for instance, considering some kind of generalized DFT).

Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/830839/2451
